# Rails nested routing for dynamic pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my Rails app I have pages which are stored in the database.

So for example:

```
id: 1
name: 'About'
slug: 'about'
parent_id: null

id: 2
name: 'Team'
slug: 'team'
parent_id: 1

id: 3
name: 'Cameron'
slug: 'cameron'
parent_id: 2
```

The slug is used to access them via the routing like so:

```
match '/:slug' => 'pages#show', :via => :get, :as => :page
```

So I could access those pages at:

```
/about
/team
/cameron
```

What I want to do is use the `parent_id` so that the routing becomes:

```
/about/team/cameron
```

Can this be achieved using routing alone? Or do I need to do something else as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a help at [Friendly gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), it simplifies routing with slugs a lot.

Alternative options to define routes like

As far as I know there's no good way to routes with dynamic paramlinks, you can create a named route to capture pretty nested pages path:

```
 get '/p/*id', :to => 'pages#show', :as => :nested_pages
```

Also, make sure you update slug of your page object to have nested urls, i.e.: append parent pages' slug to it. For example:

```
 page1.slug = '/about'
 page2.slug = '/about/team' # team is a child of about
 page3.slug = '/about/team/cameron' # cameron is a child of team
```

so that you can be made it like this

```
 get '/p/*id', :to => 'pages#show', :via => :get, :as => :nested_pages or pages
```

So, to make this work, you can probably change generate_slug method in your Page model class:

```
 def generate_slug
   name_as_slug = name.parameterize
   if parent.present?
     self.slug = [parent.slug, (slug.blank? ? name_as_slug : slug.split('/').last)].join('/')
   else
     self.slug = name_as_slug if slug.blank?
   end
 end
```

Comment: I actually really like this for generating a permalink. I've modified your code to be like this: `def generate_permalink
    name_as_permalink = slug.parameterize
    if parent_id.present?
      parent = Page.where(:id => parent_id).first
      self.permalink = [parent.permalink, (permalink.blank? ? name_as_permalink : permalink.split('/').last)].join('/')
    else
      self.permalink = name_as_permalink if permalink.blank?
    end
  end`

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this with nested routes, but you can with [route globbing and wildcards](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments). Let me outline the steps it probably takes to realize it, for you:

1. Add a wild card route like `get '*path', to: 'pages#show'` to the end of your routes file, otherwise it will match all other get requests.
2. Get the record for the `params['path']` in the `pages#show` action.

Start with the last segment and try to find it. If you don't find it, the page doesn't exist. If you get results for the last slug segment, check out their parants, if they match with the next slug segment and so on.

If it's going to be a huge tree, this solution probably creates a performance problem. Then you could implement something that stores the path somewhere or use solutions like the PostgreSQL [`ltree`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html).

Comment: "If you get results for the last slug segment, check out their parants, if they match with the next slug segment and so on." Could you show an example of how I might do this?

Comment: Maybe something like https://gist.github.com/openscript/7199e9b5515c45a4b7bc05d23dd7e9aa will work. It's kind of pseudo-ruby code. You need to adapt a few things.

Comment: Are we not just interested in the last page of the slug? Why do you need to loop through the rest of the pages?

Comment: And what is `current = current.parent.where(slug: s)` needed for? As we would just want to get the last page?

Comment: This on its own seems to work: `@page = Page.find_by(slug: params[:slug].split('/').reverse.first)` so I'd be interested to know what your reasons are for the other code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Cameron: You don't have to loop through them, if a slug is globally unique, but usually it's only unique in it's hierarchy level and not globally.